# Double quotes used in where statement for column name

Tags: sql, r, database, dbeaver

I am converting someone else's code from an R script for another region. In the R code the following SQL code is being called.

```
select MARA1.MATNR,  MAKT1.MAKTX as Description
     from CONSUMPTION_US.US_E31_MARA as MARA1
     left join CONSUMPTION_US.US_E31_MAKT as MAKT1
     on MARA1.MATNR = MAKT1.MATNR
     where MAKT1."SPRAS" = 'D'
```

My question is in the where statement why is "" around SPRAS. I have never seen this before and when I test in the DBMS, I am able to run the query with or without the double quotes. Is this providing some benefit I'm unaware of?

I expected the "" around SPRAS to cause an error when trying to run the code and found that it did not. However not using "" around SPRAS also runs successfully and the result seems to be the same.

Comment: The double quotes makes it a _delimited identifier_ - which can be the same as as reserved word, or contain space and other strange characters. Not needed here as you've already found out.